# CSS-локация элемента по параметрам вложенного

Tags: автоматизация, selenium, css

Добрый день!

В рамках задачи по переделке Selenium-скрипта
возникла проблема с заменой **x-path** локатора на **css-локатор**.
Буду благодарен, если кто-то более опытный
подскажет, как получить из xpath-локатора вида

```
xpath=//div/div[@id="mLoc"][a/@href="go.htm"]
```

css-локатор.
*То есть необходимо выбрать все **div**-элементы c атрибутом ***id="mLoc"***, имеющие
вложенный элемент **a** c атрибутом **href="go.htm"**, являющиеся дочерними
лементами других ***div***-элементов.*

Comment: http://autotestgroup.com/ru/blog/85.html

Comment: Благодарю за линку, изучил внимательно материал. В нём не даётся ответа на вопрос "как выбрать при помощи css-локатора элемент по атрибутам вложенных (дочерних) элементов?", на который, по сути, я и ищу ответ. Всё приведенные примеры позволяют осуществлять выбор только по атрибутам текущих элементов (но не дочерних!).

Comment: Я про Selenium первый раз слышу, потому точно не скажу, но попробуй просто другой подход, например, сделать обертку div-элементов class-ом и повторить "фокус"

Answer (score 1):

```
css_locator = 'div div[id="mLoc"] a[href="go.htm"]'
```

кажется так. [5 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) - тут полное руководство, возможно, Ваш локатор можно упростить.